# ¿Font Awesome tiene limitación real de páginas vistas?

Tags: font-awesome, icons, google-fonts

Estoy utilizando Font Awesome en mi sitio web con la versión "free". Hace ya unos meses que lo utilizo. Hoy me acabo de dar cuenta desde su sitio web que para la versión gratuita hay una limitación de 1000 pageviews por mes. La verdad es que tengo bastantes más páginas vistas al mes, pero me preocupa que de alguna forma, esta limitación se haga efectiva y afecte a la estética del sitio web.

¿Alguien utiliza Font Awesome y le ha pasado esto?
¿Es mejor que cambie todos los iconos del sitio por otros?

He visto Google Fonts y tiene buena pinta, a parte, veo que no tienes que almacenar archivos como Font Awesome y por lo tanto, vas recibiendo automáticamente las novedades que metan.

Answer (score 0):

He visto, por si a alguien le sirve, que ese límite no se aplica si cargas los iconos desde tu propio servidor.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).